Primeng 16 how to override default sorting icons in Angular 16
using this :
<p-sortIcon class="icon" [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
tried:
<p-sortIcon class="icon" sortAscIcon="pi-sort-up" sortDescIcon="pi-sort-down" sortNoneIcon="pi-sort-alt" [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>

but this is not working, there should be some clean way to override the sorting icons without using CSS changes.
